# finding the dp state ZUMA spoj

Tags: algorithm

i am trying to solve this spoj problem
http://www.spoj.pl/problems/ZUMA

i am unable to find a possible dp state .

can someone guide me what would be a possible dp state for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already accepted that problem in SPOJ.
My state is, from position `i` to `j` with `p` equals elements. For transition you should consider two case:

1. Insert how many piece in position `i` like you need to exploit that piece, then we will have the same problem but consider `i+1` to `j`
2. Let's say `q` is the position of an ahead element equal to the piece in `i`. We should consider solving the problem from `i` to `q-1` and then from `q` to `j` for every `q`.